# Make Call in Android Application using default call application

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I am using following code to make a call from my android application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);                 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9898989898"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This opens Intent Chooser if Skype is installed in phone. What i want is it should directly make call from default call application.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/_oxhs-_fUjQ)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");`

Like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");               
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9898989898"));
startActivity(intent);
```

---

But better is to let the user to choose.

Read more at [How to call from Android Native Dialers, ignore other dialers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/_oxhs-_fUjQ)

Comment: +1 comment "but better is to let the user choose". If I can make the call with a free VOIP provider I want to use that one!

Comment: Thanks. This worked. And i want to perform operations based on call events i receive thats why i've choosen to make call using default app.

Comment: While this may work on some devices, it crashes on mine. COvayurt's answer below works for me

Comment: @Vinay Yes correct. This is not a generic answer. But if you research more on the solution which you are suggesting, you will find a BIG mistake. What if I create a application with package name like "com.call.test" or "call.pankaj.xyz" or "pankaj.call.test"? That solution can send intent to these applications also. Even when My application do not handle call feature. Correct? Choice is your, and congs you find your solution :)

Comment: @Pankaj You're absolutely correct however, it is not usual having more than one "system apps" with similar package name. Your answer is correct but COvaurt's answer is better; also it will not crash if no such package found

Comment: @Vinay Choice is yours. Still that code has some security vulnerability. But if you are happy with that code, then yes that is perfect. Because no code is perfect until it works for you.

Answer (score 10):

For a generic use, you can implement like below.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "1111111111"));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(callIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

for(int j = 0 ; j < activities.size() ; j++)
{

    if(activities.get(j).toString().toLowerCase().contains("com.android.phone"))
    {
         callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
    }
    else if(activities.get(j).toString().toLowerCase().contains("call"))
    {
         String pack = (activities.get(j).toString().split("[ ]")[1].split("[/]")[0]);
         callIntent.setPackage(pack);
    }
}

context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Also you have to add this intent-filter to activity or receiver etc. in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity>
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
      <data android:scheme="tel" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Finally don't forget to add permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, unlike the accepted answer which seems to be device dependant.

Comment: This is correct answer, accepted answer is not generic and may not work across devices..

Answer (score 1):

find all app with dial ability

```
fun getPackagesOfDialerApps(context: Context): List<String> {
    val packageNames = ArrayList<String>()
    // Declare action which target application listen to initiate phone call
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_DIAL
    // Query for all those applications
    val resolveInfos = context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
    // Read package name of all those applications
    for (resolveInfo in resolveInfos) {
        val activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo
        packageNames.add(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName)
    }
    return packageNames
}
```

call method

```
val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:02188888888"))
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
context?.let {
    for(dialerApp in Utils.getPackagesOfDialerApps(it)){
        val appPackageName= dialerApp.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
        if(appPackageName == "com.android.phone" ||
            appPackageName  == "com.android.server.telecom" ||
            appPackageName == "com.samsung.android.contacts"){
            callIntent.setPackage(appPackageName)
            break
        }
    }
}
try {
    startActivity(callIntent)
} catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException){
    callIntent.setPackage(null)
    startActivity(callIntent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Kotlin version of @COvayurt code, for rest of the code you can follow from his answer.

```
                        val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
                        callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:" + "$it")
                        callIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        var activities = mutableListOf<ResolveInfo>()
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                            activities =  packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                                callIntent,
                                PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY.toLong())
                            )
                        } else {
                            activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
                                callIntent,
                                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
                            )
                        }

                        for (j in activities.indices) {
                            if (activities[j].toString().lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                                    .contains("com.android.phone")
                            ) {
                                callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone")
                            } else if (activities[j].toString().lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                                    .contains("call")
                            ) {
                                val pack = activities[j].toString().split("[ ]".toRegex())
                                    .dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }
                                    .toTypedArray()[1].split("[/]".toRegex())
                                    .dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()[0]
                                callIntent.setPackage(pack)
                            }
                        }

                        startActivity(callIntent)
```