# Intent Action Call in Android 5

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

I have this code, that works fine in Android 4.4 and previous:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);         
intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in Android 5.0 Lollipop this code doesn't work, and shows this exception:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxx pkg=com.android.phone }
```

[In the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), this `Intent` doesn't appear deprecated:

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: No required set package try to remove setPackage().

Comment: the reason for using a package is that i want to use the default phone app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like the package name has been changed from

```
com.android.phone
```

to

```
com.android.server.telecom.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using the action String manually encoded is to use the default `intent` like so:

```
Intent out = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL );
out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("+12345#123")));
startActivity(out);
```

This will pass the intent to the system and all apps with phone capability will respond instead of the specific one determined via the action String

Comment: This code works, but the reason for using a package is that i want to use the default phone app.

Comment: You are having problem with lollipop because they might have changed the package name .(If you read about intent you do'nt need package name to start Activity)

Comment: if you have other apps, like Skype, you must be select an option first

Comment: but you can also call from skype what diff does it make (This intent give you options to choose from )

Comment: I want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211795/make-call-in-android-application-using-default-call-application, but in Android 5.0

Comment: @Arun Salaria: your code is **NOT ok**, it will display the intent chooser (if you have more installed for ACTION_CALL, like skype,viber,etc). The poster wanted to make a call directly on the default phone dialer.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to call `com.android.phone` but it's not there. No miracles. It's not gonna work. Either the package is named differently or you are using semi-backed emulator or so with missing stuff. Not to mention you must always have `try/catch` around `startActivity()` as there's no guarantee it gonna success (especially when targeting external packages)

Comment: com.android.phone should be there, because is a real device, and it's the default phone app.

In a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4 it works. In the same Nexus 5 with Android 5 doesn't work.

I would like to know the reason

Comment: should? seems you are guessing instead of checking.

Comment: A phone must have the phone app. It is not a miracle or guessing

Comment: geezz, and its package id must com.android.phone?

Comment: In Android 4.4 it is. In Android 5.0 I don't know

Comment: then check it instead of writing comments that do not push thing forward.

Comment: I have executed a "ps" command in the shell of the phone, and the process "com.android.phone" exists. If I make the question, is because I don't have the solution. Do you have?

Answer (score -2):

This one worked for me on Android 4.4:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setPackage("com.android.dialer");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1111111111"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

If using Eclipse, open the system dialer app and in DDMS, check for the name of the dialer package; in my case was "com.android.dialer".

Comment: What the user asked also works for him on android 4.4 and he needs the modification for android 5.0. Also, you didn't add the phone number to your data