# always call Phone Call app when user dial to Contact Number from my app (Android) in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a problem when a user dials a number from my app, And if user settings have another app as the default app (Skype, Viber, etc...) Then it does not open the default device calling application for that device but in turn opens other apps (Skype, Viber, ...). What i want is that my application opens up the default device dialer is it possible?
Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far can you show us your current code for opening the dialer?

Comment: @G.hakim I only use code after: CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer.MakePhoneCall(numberPhone);

Comment: Are you using Xamarin forms or native xamarin android (Just to be clear )

Comment: @G.hakim I using Xamarin forms

Comment: Why not try this : Device.OpenUri(new Uri(String.Format("tel:{0}", numberPhone)));

Comment: Check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/launching-the-phone-dialer-activity-using-xamarin-android-application) out @HuuBaoNguyen

Comment: I have a case such as: when user dials a contact number from my app. My app will show call app (Phone call app of device, skype, viber, etc...) for user chosse. User choose Skype, but later they want call use Phone Call app default of device. How to change call app in this case?

Comment: I want when user dials a contact number from my app, my app always open by phone call app of device?

Comment: I want such as Android Native: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211795/make-call-in-android-application-using-default-call-application
But in Xamarin Forms! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found for solution on the problem:
At your Shared Code, then You can only access that from your Android platform specific project. Add codes after:

```
    Intent intentCall = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial);
    intentCall.SetData(Uri.Parse($"tel:{phone}"));                
    intentCall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);                
    PackageManager pm = Forms.Context.PackageManager;
    IList activities = pm.QueryIntentActivities(intentCall, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);                
    foreach (ResolveInfo item in activities)
    {
        if (item.ActivityInfo.ToString().ToLower().Contains("com.android.phone"))
        {
            intentCall.SetPackage("com.android.phone"); 
            break;                    

        }                   
        else if (item.ActivityInfo.ToString().ToLower().Contains("call"))
        {
            intentCall.SetPackage("com.android.server.telecom"); 
            break;
        }
    }                
    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intentCall);
```

Or Use Code after:

```
    Intent intentCall = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
    intentCall.SetData(Uri.Parse($"tel:{phone}"));                
    intentCall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);                
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop || Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.LollipopMr1)
    {
        intentCall.SetPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
    }                
    else
    {
        intentCall.SetPackage("com.android.phone");
    }
    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intentCall);
```

Comment: Can reference code Android native at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211795/make-call-in-android-application-using-default-call-application